# How do you use a set Interval with awaitMessages in discord.js, I wanna make it sequential

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
const m = await message.channel.send("Calculating ping (47%)");
    m.delete();
    const m1 = await message.channel.send('Calculating ping (81%)');
    m1.delete();
    const m2 = await message.channel.send("Calculating ping (100%)");
    m2.edit(`**Discord.JS API Latency is **${Math.round(bot.ping)}ms.`);
```

I want to make this sequential and edit the message of when it's calculating the ping.

Answer (score 0):

`.send()` returns a promise. You could use the `.edit()` method on it, like so:

```
message.channel.send("Calculating ping (47%)").then(m => {m.edit('Calculating ping (81%)')})
```

[more on .send()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) | [more on .edit()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit)

Comment: yea but i wanna also repeat that process further, also in a timely manner